# Tensorflow on Java: how to perform RGB to BGR operation?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I need to convert my 3-D tensor containing RGB image to BGR.

All the sources I've found on the web use python and they refer to operations that are either absent or different on java:

1. reverse does not accept an index but a boolean as second input
2. I've found the stack/unstack method, but unstack does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack` and `Unstack` operations are actually called as they have previously been on the other platforms, that is, `Pack` and `Unpack`. *

So, to perform the requested operation of transforming a Tensor representing an image in RGB to an image in BGR, the unstack/stack way can be followed.

```
    public <T> Output<T> rgbToBgr(Output<T> input) {
        return stackReverted(unstack(input));
    }

    // where g is Graph
    public <T> Output<T>[] unstack(Output<T> input) {
        return (Output<T>[]) g.opBuilder("Unpack", "Unpack")
                .addInput(input)
                .setAttr("axis", -1)
                .setAttr("num", 3)
                .build().outputList(0, 3);
    }


    public <T> Output<T> stackReverted(Output<T>[] input){
        GraphOperationBuilder graphOperationBuilder = g.opBuilder("Pack", "Pack")
                .setAttr("axis", -1);
        Output<T>[] newInput = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            newInput[i] = input[input.length - 1 - i];
        graphOperationBuilder.addInputList(newInput);
        return graphOperationBuilder.build().output(0);
    }
```

- There is no trace anywhere. If anybody can find documentation for Java, please post it.

Comment: These operations are named [`Unstack`](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/blob/master/tensorflow-core/tensorflow-core-api/src/gen/java/org/tensorflow/op/core/Unstack.java) and [`Stack`](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/blob/master/tensorflow-core/tensorflow-core-api/src/gen/java/org/tensorflow/op/core/Stack.java) respectively in TF Java. So given an instance of `org.tensorflow.op.Ops` named `tf`, it is possible to simply invoke `tf.unstack(input, 3, Unstack.axis(-1))` and `tf.stack(inputs, Stack.axis(-1))`.